# How to Append String to End of Same Line of Git Commit Message with Git Commit Hook

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I'm trying to append a string to the end of a Git commit message and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932092/can-i-add-a-string-to-my-commit-messages-before-sending-them-to-svn-in-git-svn) was a very helpful step in the right direction.

So far, this is working in .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg but appending my string on a new line:

```
echo "foo" >> "$1"
```

with output:

```
"Initial commit
 foo"
```

I was looking into how to append on the same line with `echo` but I'm unable to successfully pass the `-n` argument to echo in a commit hook. In addition to `echo`, I also tried `printf` to no avail as well.

I'm looking to have the my commit message look like:

```
"Initial commit foo"
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add to the end of a line containing a pattern - with sed or awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591744/add-to-the-end-of-a-line-containing-a-pattern-with-sed-or-awk)

Comment: @larsks Thanks but I think the issue I'm having is specific to git hooks in particular.

Comment: @TomHanlon: no, it's totally generic.  The commit-message file (argument `$1`) is an ordinary file and must be edited in the usual ordinary ways.  Appending to the file appends to the file, not to lines *within* the file.  Using `echo -n` is no help as the file already has a newline after its last line.

Comment: Thanks @torek -- looks like my path forward will be identifying the blank trailing line, removing it, and appending to the final line using sed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it after revisiting this recently. Here's my prepare-commit-hook:

```
# Append string/emoji to each commit message
commitMsgFile = "$1"
existingMsg = `cat $commitMsgFile`
echo "$existingMsg :shipit:" > "$1"
```

I was unable to pass echo arguments but I was able to overwrite the original commit message with the addition of the string on the same line. Hope this helps someone in the future.